# What is the user datatype in this Mongoid, Devise and Rails 3 Tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, devise, mongoid

I am using this [tutorial/app template](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-devise/tree/master/app) to play around with rails3 and mongoid and the generated datatype for user_id clearly isn't integer as the first user has this id: 4defd4b5ab104d5ea1000001.

What is the datatype used by Devise or the tutorial and for future reference where did you find it defined in the app template/devise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type is called "ObjectId" and is a native BSON type. BSON is a binary JSON-like data format used internally by mongo.

See, http://bsonspec.org/#/specification for the BSON specs and http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs for a discussion on this type.

ObjectIds are the default unique identifier of mongo documents (the "_id" field) and are usually client generated (upserts being the exception). They are (practically) collision safe as they have a time, process id, machine id and a random/increment component.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am still wondering where the data gets defined in rails with mongoid.  It isn't in the migrations since mongodb and mongoid don't have them and it isn't in the models (I looked).  So does anybody know where it is hiding?

Comment: In Mongoid, fields are all defined in the model, unlike active record - where you define the fields in your migrations. You can read more about setting up documents [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/fields.html).